# Thunderbird+Lightning returns "tentative" automatically on invitations

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

Whenever I receive an invitation (through an Exchange server) TB+Lightning returns a "tentative" status automatically. Before I even open the invitation.

I have TB 31.5.0 and Lightning 3.3.3 (with Exchange EWS Provider 3.2.2)

Any idea how can I change this annoying default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The newest version of exchangecalendar (v3.3.2 RC1) from https://github.com/Ericsson/exchangecalendar/releases fixed the problem for me.

After updating, right-click on your exchange calendar -> Exchange (EWS) Properties -> Automatic Processing: There is now a checkbox called "Automatically mark event as tentative and send response to organizer".